# How to add in instance field which not in model but created in Django form?Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a model Book:

```
class Book(core.BaseModel):

    name = models.ForeignKey(
        FishingGear, verbose_name="Name", on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='name',
    )
    library = models.ForeignKey(
        Library, models.PROTECT, related_name='library_places',
        verbose_name='Library',
    )
    tag_number = models.PositiveIntegerField('Tag Number', validators=[
        MinValueValidator(1),
        MaxValueValidator(MAX_TAG_NUMBER),
    ])
```

In forms.py I created new field :

```
class BookChangeStatusForm(core.ModelForm):
    start_tag_number = forms.IntegerField(label='Start number', min_value=1)
```

In the same forms.py I have method which takes old data and create new book!But I want that without tag_number it will create field 'start_tag_number':

```
 def save(self, commit=True):
        # instance = super().save(commit=False)
        instance = Book.objects.create(
            name=self.instance.name,
            library=self.instance.library,
            tag_number=self.instance.**start_tag_number**,
        )


        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ()
```

But I got Error:

```
Book object has no attribute 'start_tag_number'
```

My views.py

```
class BookTagView(core.UpdateView):
    form_class = BookChangeStatusForm
    template_name = 'book/book_tag.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('book:book-list')
```

I want to take in forms.py OLD instance in UpdateView and create new instance with old data but without 'tag_number' insert 'start_tag_number'!Please help me to undestand where is mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Your form's save method should be like

```
    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super().save(commit=False)
        instance.tag_number = self.cleaned_data['start_tag_number']
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `self.cleaned_data['start_tag_number']`? `self.start_tag_number` is the form field definition?